BuildingConnected API "Get Bids" is returning an empty JSON array
I am calling https://developer.api.autodesk.com/construction/buildingconnected/v2/bids but get an empty array in the response.  I chatted with Autodesk support who verified that I have a Building Connected Pro license for the office that I am in.
The API call completed successfully without any errors.  I refresh the token every hour and do not receive errors concerning the token.
I added the "updatedAT" filter to pull from 08/28/24, but the response was still an empty array.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.
